# How to import module so that it can be accessed from any directory?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following project structure:

```
x/
    a.py
    b.py
main.py
```

a.py:

```
from b import *

class A:
    .....
```

main.py

```
from x.a import A

.....
```

I want to be able to run `a.py` independently as well as access its functionality through `main.py`

I'm able to run `a.py` but when I try to import it as shown in `main.py`, the module is unable to be found. I can fix this problem by adding the following line to `a.py`:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

but this feels hacky. Is there a better way to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: what is your `PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark the directory "x" as a package to be able to load anything off it.

As stated in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) of Python, you have to create an empty "__init__.py" file in the root of "x" to mark it off as a package.

Then your directory structure should look something like this:

```
.
└── x
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── a.py
    └── b.py
└── main.py
```

You may want to edit "a.py" to load the modules relative to the package it is in using a period to represent the current package:

```
# x/a.py
from .b import *

class A:
    # rest of your code
```